# When does PermGen space get cleared?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, permgen

I am trying to determine if my application has a memory leak, or if it is in fact just running out of memory due to the number of classes I have.

My question is: When does the PermGen space get cleared? I am running an application inside of Tomcat6. Does the PermGen space get cleared when tomcat is restarted, or when the JVM or whole server gets restarted?

Comment: *Does the PermGen space get cleared when tomcat is restarted, or when the JVM or whole server gets restarted?* Yes. Your three examples are (typically) the same thing. Now, if you were to ask about **redeployment**; then that is a *little* different, and the tomcat classloader is responsible for the life-cycle.

Comment: Maybe [this](http://www.zulutown.com/blog/2009/03/12/solving-tomcat-outofmemoryerror-heap-space-and-permgen-space/) will help.

Answer (score 0):

PermGen space gets cleared at minimum when Tomcat is restarted. You don't need to reboot the entire server to clear it.

The JVM will restart with Tomcat.